# Convert 3x3 array of 2x2 arrays to a 6x6 array maintaining position

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 3x3x4 array, each of the 3x3 subarrays (4-tuples, or 1x4 arrays) I want to map to a 2x2 array and stitch them together to form a 6x6 array. I'm having difficulty explaining this in words, so I hope the below illustration helps:

Here's a 3x3 array of 1x4 arrays, named `1` through `9`:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Each 1x4 array above is enumerated below:

```
1 = [a, b, c, d]
2 = [e, f, g, h]
3 = [i, j, k, l]
4 = [m, n, o, p]
5 = [q, r, s, t]
6 = [u, v, w, x]
7 = [y, z, !, @]
8 = [#, $, %, ^]
9 = [&, *, (, )]
```

I want to convert this 3x3x4 array to a bigger 6x6 array:

```
a b e f i j
c d g h k l
m n q r u v
o p s t w x
y z # $ & *
! @ % ^ ( )
```

You'll see the top-left 2x2 corresponds to the 1st 1x4 array, the top-center 2x2 is the 2nd 1x4 array, and so on.

[image]

As in the image above, `1` became `a b c d` in a 2x2 sub-array, `2` became `e f g h i` in a 2x2 sub-array. These are part of the larger 6x6 array.

I'm not sure programmatically how to do this, any ideas?

Here's some starter code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from random import uniform

# original array is 3x3
old_width = 3
old_height = 3
# subarray size
sub_width = 2
sub_height = 2
# new array is function of the above four
new_width = old_width*sub_width
new_height = old_height*sub_height

def rand_subarray():
  # makes a 1x4 subarray
  return [uniform(0.00, 1.00) for _ in range(sub_width*sub_height)]

def generate_map():
  # makes a 3x3 array of 1x4 subarrays
  return [[rand_subarray() for _ in range(old_width)] for _ in range(old_height)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
  map = generate_map()
```

If it makes a difference, this is for a self organizing map.

Comment: When you say array, what data type are you after using in Python? Just lists, or numpy arrays, perhaps data frames?

Comment: @Grismar lists, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide code for your actual situation, so I had to guess at the exact representation, but here's a basic way to do what you're doing:

```
example = [
    [
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
        ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'],
    ],
    [
        ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p'],
        ['q', 'r', 's', 't'],
        ['u', 'v', 'w', 'x']
    ],
    [
        ['y', 'z', '!', '@'],
        ['#', '$', '%', '^'],
        ['&', '*', '(', ')']
    ]
]

def flatten(data):
    for row in data:
        yield [x for part in [block[:2] for block in row] for x in part]
        yield [x for part in [block[2:] for block in row] for x in part]


print(list(flatten(example)))
```

If you need it to work for a similar setup where you have blocks of 9 that need to get split into 3 lines (so, starting with a 3x3x9 array), this function still works for 3x3x4, but you can pass it any such array with an appropriate bite_size:

```
def flatten(data, bite_size):
    for row in data:
        for i in range(0, len(row[0]), bite_size):
            yield [x for part in [block[i:i+bite_size] for block in row] for x in part]
```

Or a more direct approach:

```
result = [
    [x for part in [block[i:i+bite_size] for block in row] for x in part] 
    for row in example for i in range(0, len(row[0]), 2)  # 2 here is 'bite_size'
]
```

Running this:

```
for line in result:
    print(line)
```

Outputs:

```
['a', 'b', 'e', 'f', 'i', 'j']
['c', 'd', 'g', 'h', 'k', 'l']
['m', 'n', 'q', 'r', 'u', 'v']
['o', 'p', 's', 't', 'w', 'x']
['y', 'z', '#', '$', '&', '*']
['!', '@', '%', '^', '(', ')']
```

If you're looking for both a function to flatten and unflatten:

```
def flatten(data, bite_size):
    return [
        [x for part in [block[i:i+bite_size] for block in row] for x in part]
        for row in data for i in range(0, len(row[0]), bite_size)
    ]


def unflatten(data, bite_size):
    return [[
        sum(parts, [])
        for parts in zip(
            *[[row[c:c+bite_size]
               for c in range(0, len(row), bite_size)]
               for row in data[r:r+bite_size]]
        )
    ] for r in range(0, len(data), bite_size)]
```

You'll find that, with these:

```
print(unflatten(flatten(example)) == example)
```

Will be `True`.

Comment: I added some starting code. Is your method reversible, i.e. get back the original given this output?

Comment: Since the algorithm you ask for is inherently destructive, it cannot possibly be its own inverse. However, given a `bite_size`, you could of course fairly simply write function with the inverse effect.

Comment: See the edited answer for such a function. From your added code, it appears you want `bite_size` to be different for the x and y direction, that's just a few more changes to the above and left to the reader as an exercise :)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea!

```
width = 3
height = 3
sub_width = 2
sub_height = 2

max_length=len(str(width * height * sub_width * sub_height))+1

def formatArray3D(array):
  return list(map(formatArray,array))
def formatArray(array):
  return list(map(formatNum,array))
def formatNum(Num):
  return str(Num).ljust(max_length)

array = [[[ ( i * height*width*sub_height*sub_width ) + ( j * sub_height*sub_width ) + k for k in range(sub_height*sub_width)] for j in range(width)] for i in range(height)]
print(*map(formatArray3D,array),sep="\n")

print("----------------CONVERT----------------")

converted_array = [[array[i//sub_height][j//sub_width][i%sub_height * sub_width + j%sub_width ] for j in range(width*sub_width)] for i in range(height*sub_height)]
print(*map(formatArray,converted_array),sep="\n")
```

output:

```
[['0  ', '1  ', '2  ', '3  '], ['4  ', '5  ', '6  ', '7  '], ['8  ', '9  ', '10 ', '11 ']]
[['36 ', '37 ', '38 ', '39 '], ['40 ', '41 ', '42 ', '43 '], ['44 ', '45 ', '46 ', '47 ']]
[['72 ', '73 ', '74 ', '75 '], ['76 ', '77 ', '78 ', '79 '], ['80 ', '81 ', '82 ', '83 ']]
----------------CONVERT----------------
['0  ', '1  ', '4  ', '5  ', '8  ', '9  ']
['2  ', '3  ', '6  ', '7  ', '10 ', '11 ']
['36 ', '37 ', '40 ', '41 ', '44 ', '45 ']
['38 ', '39 ', '42 ', '43 ', '46 ', '47 ']
['72 ', '73 ', '76 ', '77 ', '80 ', '81 ']
['74 ', '75 ', '78 ', '79 ', '82 ', '83 ']
```

with these inputs,

```
width = 5
height = 5
sub_width = 5
sub_height = 5
```

output:

```
[['0   ', '1   ', '2   ', '3   ', '4   ', '5   ', '6   ', '7   ', '8   ', '9   ', '10  ', '11  ', '12  ', '13  ', '14  ', '15  ', '16  ', '17  ', '18  ', '19  ', '20  ', '21  ', '22  ', '23  ', '24  '], ['25  ', '26  ', '27  ', '28  ', '29  ', '30  ', '31  ', '32  ', '33  ', '34  ', '35  ', '36  ', '37  ', '38  ', '39  ', '40  ', '41  ', '42  ', '43  ', '44  ', '45  ', '46  ', '47  ', '48  ', '49  '], ['50  ', '51  ', '52  ', '53  ', '54  ', '55  ', '56  ', '57  ', '58  ', '59  ', '60  ', '61  ', '62  ', '63  ', '64  ', '65  ', '66  ', '67  ', '68  ', '69  ', '70  ', '71  ', '72  ', '73  ', '74  '], ['75  ', '76  ', '77  ', '78  ', '79  ', '80  ', '81  ', '82  ', '83  ', '84  ', '85  ', '86  ', '87  ', '88  ', '89  ', '90  ', '91  ', '92  ', '93  ', '94  ', '95  ', '96  ', '97  ', '98  ', '99  '], ['100 ', '101 ', '102 ', '103 ', '104 ', '105 ', '106 ', '107 ', '108 ', '109 ', '110 ', '111 ', '112 ', '113 ', '114 ', '115 ', '116 ', '117 ', '118 ', '119 ', '120 ', '121 ', '122 ', '123 ', '124 ']]
[['625 ', '626 ', '627 ', '628 ', '629 ', '630 ', '631 ', '632 ', '633 ', '634 ', '635 ', '636 ', '637 ', '638 ', '639 ', '640 ', '641 ', '642 ', '643 ', '644 ', '645 ', '646 ', '647 ', '648 ', '649 '], ['650 ', '651 ', '652 ', '653 ', '654 ', '655 ', '656 ', '657 ', '658 ', '659 ', '660 ', '661 ', '662 ', '663 ', '664 ', '665 ', '666 ', '667 ', '668 ', '669 ', '670 ', '671 ', '672 ', '673 ', '674 '], ['675 ', '676 ', '677 ', '678 ', '679 ', '680 ', '681 ', '682 ', '683 ', '684 ', '685 ', '686 ', '687 ', '688 ', '689 ', '690 ', '691 ', '692 ', '693 ', '694 ', '695 ', '696 ', '697 ', '698 ', '699 '], ['700 ', '701 ', '702 ', '703 ', '704 ', '705 ', '706 ', '707 ', '708 ', '709 ', '710 ', '711 ', '712 ', '713 ', '714 ', '715 ', '716 ', '717 ', '718 ', '719 ', '720 ', '721 ', '722 ', '723 ', '724 '], ['725 ', '726 ', '727 ', '728 ', '729 ', '730 ', '731 ', '732 ', '733 ', '734 ', '735 ', '736 ', '737 ', '738 ', '739 ', '740 ', '741 ', '742 ', '743 ', '744 ', '745 ', '746 ', '747 ', '748 ', '749 ']]
[['1250', '1251', '1252', '1253', '1254', '1255', '1256', '1257', '1258', '1259', '1260', '1261', '1262', '1263', '1264', '1265', '1266', '1267', '1268', '1269', '1270', '1271', '1272', '1273', '1274'], ['1275', '1276', '1277', '1278', '1279', '1280', '1281', '1282', '1283', '1284', '1285', '1286', '1287', '1288', '1289', '1290', '1291', '1292', '1293', '1294', '1295', '1296', '1297', '1298', '1299'], ['1300', '1301', '1302', '1303', '1304', '1305', '1306', '1307', '1308', '1309', '1310', '1311', '1312', '1313', '1314', '1315', '1316', '1317', '1318', '1319', '1320', '1321', '1322', '1323', '1324'], ['1325', '1326', '1327', '1328', '1329', '1330', '1331', '1332', '1333', '1334', '1335', '1336', '1337', '1338', '1339', '1340', '1341', '1342', '1343', '1344', '1345', '1346', '1347', '1348', '1349'], ['1350', '1351', '1352', '1353', '1354', '1355', '1356', '1357', '1358', '1359', '1360', '1361', '1362', '1363', '1364', '1365', '1366', '1367', '1368', '1369', '1370', '1371', '1372', '1373', '1374']]
[['1875', '1876', '1877', '1878', '1879', '1880', '1881', '1882', '1883', '1884', '1885', '1886', '1887', '1888', '1889', '1890', '1891', '1892', '1893', '1894', '1895', '1896', '1897', '1898', '1899'], ['1900', '1901', '1902', '1903', '1904', '1905', '1906', '1907', '1908', '1909', '1910', '1911', '1912', '1913', '1914', '1915', '1916', '1917', '1918', '1919', '1920', '1921', '1922', '1923', '1924'], ['1925', '1926', '1927', '1928', '1929', '1930', '1931', '1932', '1933', '1934', '1935', '1936', '1937', '1938', '1939', '1940', '1941', '1942', '1943', '1944', '1945', '1946', '1947', '1948', '1949'], ['1950', '1951', '1952', '1953', '1954', '1955', '1956', '1957', '1958', '1959', '1960', '1961', '1962', '1963', '1964', '1965', '1966', '1967', '1968', '1969', '1970', '1971', '1972', '1973', '1974'], ['1975', '1976', '1977', '1978', '1979', '1980', '1981', '1982', '1983', '1984', '1985', '1986', '1987', '1988', '1989', '1990', '1991', '1992', '1993', '1994', '1995', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999']]
[['2500', '2501', '2502', '2503', '2504', '2505', '2506', '2507', '2508', '2509', '2510', '2511', '2512', '2513', '2514', '2515', '2516', '2517', '2518', '2519', '2520', '2521', '2522', '2523', '2524'], ['2525', '2526', '2527', '2528', '2529', '2530', '2531', '2532', '2533', '2534', '2535', '2536', '2537', '2538', '2539', '2540', '2541', '2542', '2543', '2544', '2545', '2546', '2547', '2548', '2549'], ['2550', '2551', '2552', '2553', '2554', '2555', '2556', '2557', '2558', '2559', '2560', '2561', '2562', '2563', '2564', '2565', '2566', '2567', '2568', '2569', '2570', '2571', '2572', '2573', '2574'], ['2575', '2576', '2577', '2578', '2579', '2580', '2581', '2582', '2583', '2584', '2585', '2586', '2587', '2588', '2589', '2590', '2591', '2592', '2593', '2594', '2595', '2596', '2597', '2598', '2599'], ['2600', '2601', '2602', '2603', '2604', '2605', '2606', '2607', '2608', '2609', '2610', '2611', '2612', '2613', '2614', '2615', '2616', '2617', '2618', '2619', '2620', '2621', '2622', '2623', '2624']]
----------------CONVERT----------------
['0   ', '1   ', '2   ', '3   ', '4   ', '25  ', '26  ', '27  ', '28  ', '29  ', '50  ', '51  ', '52  ', '53  ', '54  ', '75  ', '76  ', '77  ', '78  ', '79  ', '100 ', '101 ', '102 ', '103 ', '104 ']
['5   ', '6   ', '7   ', '8   ', '9   ', '30  ', '31  ', '32  ', '33  ', '34  ', '55  ', '56  ', '57  ', '58  ', '59  ', '80  ', '81  ', '82  ', '83  ', '84  ', '105 ', '106 ', '107 ', '108 ', '109 ']
['10  ', '11  ', '12  ', '13  ', '14  ', '35  ', '36  ', '37  ', '38  ', '39  ', '60  ', '61  ', '62  ', '63  ', '64  ', '85  ', '86  ', '87  ', '88  ', '89  ', '110 ', '111 ', '112 ', '113 ', '114 ']
['15  ', '16  ', '17  ', '18  ', '19  ', '40  ', '41  ', '42  ', '43  ', '44  ', '65  ', '66  ', '67  ', '68  ', '69  ', '90  ', '91  ', '92  ', '93  ', '94  ', '115 ', '116 ', '117 ', '118 ', '119 ']
['20  ', '21  ', '22  ', '23  ', '24  ', '45  ', '46  ', '47  ', '48  ', '49  ', '70  ', '71  ', '72  ', '73  ', '74  ', '95  ', '96  ', '97  ', '98  ', '99  ', '120 ', '121 ', '122 ', '123 ', '124 ']
['625 ', '626 ', '627 ', '628 ', '629 ', '650 ', '651 ', '652 ', '653 ', '654 ', '675 ', '676 ', '677 ', '678 ', '679 ', '700 ', '701 ', '702 ', '703 ', '704 ', '725 ', '726 ', '727 ', '728 ', '729 ']
['630 ', '631 ', '632 ', '633 ', '634 ', '655 ', '656 ', '657 ', '658 ', '659 ', '680 ', '681 ', '682 ', '683 ', '684 ', '705 ', '706 ', '707 ', '708 ', '709 ', '730 ', '731 ', '732 ', '733 ', '734 ']
['635 ', '636 ', '637 ', '638 ', '639 ', '660 ', '661 ', '662 ', '663 ', '664 ', '685 ', '686 ', '687 ', '688 ', '689 ', '710 ', '711 ', '712 ', '713 ', '714 ', '735 ', '736 ', '737 ', '738 ', '739 ']
['640 ', '641 ', '642 ', '643 ', '644 ', '665 ', '666 ', '667 ', '668 ', '669 ', '690 ', '691 ', '692 ', '693 ', '694 ', '715 ', '716 ', '717 ', '718 ', '719 ', '740 ', '741 ', '742 ', '743 ', '744 ']
['645 ', '646 ', '647 ', '648 ', '649 ', '670 ', '671 ', '672 ', '673 ', '674 ', '695 ', '696 ', '697 ', '698 ', '699 ', '720 ', '721 ', '722 ', '723 ', '724 ', '745 ', '746 ', '747 ', '748 ', '749 ']
['1250', '1251', '1252', '1253', '1254', '1275', '1276', '1277', '1278', '1279', '1300', '1301', '1302', '1303', '1304', '1325', '1326', '1327', '1328', '1329', '1350', '1351', '1352', '1353', '1354']
['1255', '1256', '1257', '1258', '1259', '1280', '1281', '1282', '1283', '1284', '1305', '1306', '1307', '1308', '1309', '1330', '1331', '1332', '1333', '1334', '1355', '1356', '1357', '1358', '1359']
['1260', '1261', '1262', '1263', '1264', '1285', '1286', '1287', '1288', '1289', '1310', '1311', '1312', '1313', '1314', '1335', '1336', '1337', '1338', '1339', '1360', '1361', '1362', '1363', '1364']
['1265', '1266', '1267', '1268', '1269', '1290', '1291', '1292', '1293', '1294', '1315', '1316', '1317', '1318', '1319', '1340', '1341', '1342', '1343', '1344', '1365', '1366', '1367', '1368', '1369']
['1270', '1271', '1272', '1273', '1274', '1295', '1296', '1297', '1298', '1299', '1320', '1321', '1322', '1323', '1324', '1345', '1346', '1347', '1348', '1349', '1370', '1371', '1372', '1373', '1374']
['1875', '1876', '1877', '1878', '1879', '1900', '1901', '1902', '1903', '1904', '1925', '1926', '1927', '1928', '1929', '1950', '1951', '1952', '1953', '1954', '1975', '1976', '1977', '1978', '1979']
['1880', '1881', '1882', '1883', '1884', '1905', '1906', '1907', '1908', '1909', '1930', '1931', '1932', '1933', '1934', '1955', '1956', '1957', '1958', '1959', '1980', '1981', '1982', '1983', '1984']
['1885', '1886', '1887', '1888', '1889', '1910', '1911', '1912', '1913', '1914', '1935', '1936', '1937', '1938', '1939', '1960', '1961', '1962', '1963', '1964', '1985', '1986', '1987', '1988', '1989']
['1890', '1891', '1892', '1893', '1894', '1915', '1916', '1917', '1918', '1919', '1940', '1941', '1942', '1943', '1944', '1965', '1966', '1967', '1968', '1969', '1990', '1991', '1992', '1993', '1994']
['1895', '1896', '1897', '1898', '1899', '1920', '1921', '1922', '1923', '1924', '1945', '1946', '1947', '1948', '1949', '1970', '1971', '1972', '1973', '1974', '1995', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999']
['2500', '2501', '2502', '2503', '2504', '2525', '2526', '2527', '2528', '2529', '2550', '2551', '2552', '2553', '2554', '2575', '2576', '2577', '2578', '2579', '2600', '2601', '2602', '2603', '2604']
['2505', '2506', '2507', '2508', '2509', '2530', '2531', '2532', '2533', '2534', '2555', '2556', '2557', '2558', '2559', '2580', '2581', '2582', '2583', '2584', '2605', '2606', '2607', '2608', '2609']
['2510', '2511', '2512', '2513', '2514', '2535', '2536', '2537', '2538', '2539', '2560', '2561', '2562', '2563', '2564', '2585', '2586', '2587', '2588', '2589', '2610', '2611', '2612', '2613', '2614']
['2515', '2516', '2517', '2518', '2519', '2540', '2541', '2542', '2543', '2544', '2565', '2566', '2567', '2568', '2569', '2590', '2591', '2592', '2593', '2594', '2615', '2616', '2617', '2618', '2619']
['2520', '2521', '2522', '2523', '2524', '2545', '2546', '2547', '2548', '2549', '2570', '2571', '2572', '2573', '2574', '2595', '2596', '2597', '2598', '2599', '2620', '2621', '2622', '2623', '2624']
```

lol